# Function graph in MiKTeX

Tags: diagrams

I need to make the graph of the function in picture. I am new to MiKTeX so I can not understand the most of the errors. Could you help me?[image]       in [-2,2]

Comment: What errors? We don't know what's wrong unless we can see the errors.

Comment: Have a look at the pgfplots package. Try to run the examples given there: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=de

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. MikTeX is just one implementation of LaTeX (well adapted to Windows OS), another poplar is TeXlive. So you looking for packages, which suport drawing functions in LaTeX. Among of them are today popular `tikz`, `pgfplots`, `pstricks` etc. For all of them exist good documentation and sea of examples here on site and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-1.5)(6,16.5)
\psset{algebraic, arrowinset=0.125, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1, xunit =2,yunit = 0.4}
\psaxes[linecolor=SteelBlue, ticks=all, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue, labels=all, arrows =->, Dy=5 ](0,0)(-2.9,-2.5)(3,40) [$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=Coral, plotpoints=500, plotstyle=curve}
\psplot{-2}{2}{EXP((SIN(x))^3) + x^6 - 2*x^4 - x^3 - 1}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]